# Mongolab refuses connections

Tags: python, mongodb, mlab

I'm working on a Python program that submits data to Mongolab, and I'm running across a strange exception:

```
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database mongodb://<user>:
<password>@ds035617.mongolab.com:35617/<mydatabase>:
could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it
```

This is the offending code:

```
from mongoengine import *
connect('tablename', "mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds035617.mongolab.com:35617/<mydatabase>")
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: And? The remote machine is obviously blocking incoming traffic through a firewall. Your task to check this...not ours...

Comment: The remote machine (MongoLab) is not blocking connections from the outside (I work for MongoLab :).

Comment: @Maulwurfn, as will pointed out, it's not necessarily that the remote machine is blocking incoming traffic.  Obviously I did some checking myself before asking the question here; I'm not lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally think it's poor form to answer one's own question, but I figured out the (rather simple) answer and wanted to document it to make sure others would have it as well.

The issue was not specifying `host=` as a keyword argument in the `connect` function.  The correct function call would be:

```
from mongoengine import *
connect('tablename', host="mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds035617.mongolab.com:35617/<mydatabase>")
```

Comment: "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions" http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

A few things I would check:

(1) Why does the error message say the system is trying to connect to localhost:27017...?

(2) Why does your mongodb URI have "user" and "password" where the real username and password should be?

My guess is the problem is (2) unless you are obscuring the username and password for the sake of this posting.

If you still have trouble email support@mongolab.com and we can dig deeper with you.

-will

Comment: I'm not at all sure why it's connecting to localhost; I was wondering that myself.  Maybe `mongoengine` sets up a local proxy...?  I can't imagine why; I never had the problem before, so it never came up.  And as for (2), I am in fact obscuring the username and password, and edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a [MongoDB URI](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections) to connect, but the driver is interpreting the string as the database name and trying to connect to the default localhost:27017. According to the [mongoengine docs](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html) you want to pass that URI in as the host parameter:

---

Uri style connections are also supported as long as you include the database name - just supply the uri as the host to connect():

```
connect('project1', host='mongodb://localhost/database_name')
```